# Issue with Selenium to load all posts and then extract posts

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, web-crawler

I am going to crawl this URL https://healthunlocked.com/positivewellbeing.

I wrote the following commands to first click on `see more posts` to load all posts and then extract each post's full text. I am trying to run the code, but it takes too much time!!! I ran the code for the last 2 days, and I am still waiting to finish the run. I suppose it still tries to load posts via the first part of the code because I have not seen any output (extracted post) yet. I don't know whether I did it right?

My code is as follows:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);")
## Load all posts
while (driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="__next"]/main/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[31]/button')):
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="__next"]/main/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[31]/button').click()
    

##extract posts 
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);")
time.sleep(3)
lst_post = [x.get_attribute('href') for x in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='results-post']/a")]
for lst in lst_post:
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.get(lst)
    post_body = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[1]/main/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]")))
    like_count = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".post-action--like")))
    #print (ascii(post_body.text))
    print (post_body.text)
    print('‍\n')
```

Comment: Are you running selenium in headless mode? Otherwise it should open a new window and you should be able to see what is going on. That is, you should be able to see if the script is still loading posts or if it is done with it.

Comment: Would you please check the "While" loop to see whether I did right?

Comment: Probably not, `driver.find_element_by_xpath()` raises a `NoSuchElementException` exception when it can't find the element you specify, so I guess that, should you get to the end of the comments, the script would break instead of moving to the second part

Comment: thanks
You mean I should change "while" loop in this way?
 
while (driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="__next"]/main/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[31]/button')):
   try:
       time.sleep(5)
       driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="__next"]/main/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[31]/button').click()
   except:
       break

Comment: your #load post while loop is never stopping. Depends on how far back posts go... I can share my approach if ud like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was bored so I made my own approach.
It **scrapes** all links, visits them, goes back and **scrapes** the links that werent visited yet

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementClickInterceptedException


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait(6)
driver.get("https://healthunlocked.com/positivewellbeing/posts")
# click accept cookies
driver.find_element_by_id("ccc-notify-accept").click()
post_links = set()
while True:
    driver.get("https://healthunlocked.com/positivewellbeing/posts")
    all_posts = [post for post in
                 driver.find_element_by_class_name("results-posts").find_elements_by_class_name("results-post") if
                 "results-post" == post.get_attribute("class")]
    # handle clicking more posts
    while len(all_posts) <= len(post_links):

        see_more_posts = [btn for btn in driver.find_elements_by_class_name("btn-secondary")
                          if btn.text == "See more posts"]
        try:
            see_more_posts[0].click()
        except ElementClickInterceptedException:
            # handle floating box covering "see more posts" button
            driver.execute_script("return document.getElementsByClassName('floating-box-sign-up')[0].remove();")
            see_more_posts[0].click()
        all_posts = [post for post in driver.find_element_by_class_name("results-posts").find_elements_by_class_name("results-post") if "results-post" == post.get_attribute("class")]
    # popoulate links
    start_from = len(post_links)
    for post in all_posts[start_from:]: # len(post_links): <-- to avoid visiting same links
        # save link
        link = post.find_element_by_tag_name("a").get_attribute("href")
        post_links.add(link)

    # visit the site and scrape info
    for post_site in list(post_links)[start_from:]:

        driver.get(post_site)
        post_text = driver.find_element_by_class_name("post-body").text
        for btn in driver.find_element_by_class_name("post-actions__buttons").find_elements_by_tag_name("button"):
            if "Like" in btn.text:
                post_like = btn.text.split()[1][1]

        print(f"\n{post_text}\nLikes -->{post_like}\n")
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help. It works perfectly but it returns each post two times. It seems it extract posts from the beginning at each post-loading.

Comment: after this for loop `for post in all_posts[start_from:]` the post_links set has the correct links

Answer (score 2):

It seems this site uses an API to get the list of posts and to get the post data:

post list: https://solaris.healthunlocked.com/posts/positivewellbeing/latest

post url: https://solaris.healthunlocked.com/posts/positivewellbeing/145621054

Using `requests`, you could call these API rather than using selenium, this way it would be faster.

Also, this way, you can control when you stop scraping by recording the last post ID. eg you can start from where you've stopped scraping if necessary.

The following code gets all the posts created during last month and get their respective information:

```
import requests
import time
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

allPostUrl = 'https://solaris.healthunlocked.com/posts/positivewellbeing/latest'

now = datetime.today()
postFromTime = now + timedelta(days=-1*30) # last month

fetchAllPost = False
nextPost = ""
posts = []

while not fetchAllPost:
    url = f'{allPostUrl}{f"?createdBeforePostId={nextPost}" if nextPost else ""}'
    print(f"GET {url}")
    r = requests.get(url)
    result = r.json()
    posts.extend(result)
    if len(result) > 0 and nextPost != result[len(result)-1]["postId"]:
        lastCreated = datetime.strptime(result[len(result)-1]["dateCreated"], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
        if lastCreated < postFromTime:
            fetchAllPost = True
        else:
            nextPost = result[len(result)-1]["postId"]
    else:
        fetchAllPost = True

print(f"received {len(posts)} posts")

data = []
for idx, post in enumerate(posts):
    url = f'https://solaris.healthunlocked.com/posts/positivewellbeing/{post["postId"]}'
    print(f"[{idx+1}/{len(posts)}] GET {url}")
    r = requests.get(url)
    result = r.json()
    data.append({
        "body": result["body"],
        "likes": result["numRatings"]
    })

print(data)
```

[try this on repl.it](https://repl.it/@bertrandmartel/HealthUnlockedApi)

Comment: Many thanks for your code. I am a beginner, would you please send me a link to see how I can modify your code to start with the login page? Because I need to login, then extract the posts as the shared posts are different when you login into the website with an account.

Comment: Additionally, the code returns just 270 posts, while the page has more than 8000 posts